# How to copy the value of one data field to another table in the same SQLite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, android-studio

I would like to copy the primary key from one table to a new field in a different table within the same SQLite database.

In my League Table I have;
LeagueId
LeagueName

In my Series Table I have;
SeriesID
SeriesLeagueID
SeriesName

I want to be able to move the LeagueID into the Series table and populate the SeriesLeagueID with it.

I have done a search on this but all I can seem to find is how to copy a complete row or column from on table to another.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

MainActivity

```
//On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {



                int leagueId = leaguesList.get( position ).getId();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("value1", leagueId);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerActivity.class);
                //startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.league_id );
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

        String savedExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra( "value1" );
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        final String s = myText.toString();
        myText.setText(savedExtra);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something along the lines of the following to UPDATE the series table :-

```
UPDATE Series 
    SET SeriesLeagueID = (
        SELECT LeagueId 
        FROM League 
        WHERE Leaguename = 'Premier'
    ) 
    WHERE SeriesName = 'Test2';
```

Noting that

- the row in the League table is (from which to get the LeagueId), in this example, identified by being the row with the LeagueName column as having the value Premier (assumed you'd not know the LeaugeId in advance)
- the row to be updated is identified as the row that has the value Test2 in the SeriesName column.

### Code used for testing :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS League;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Series;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS League (LeagueId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, LeagueName TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Series (SeriesID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, SeriesLeagueID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, SeriesName TEXT);
-- Add some leagues
INSERT INTO League (LeagueName) VALUES('Premier'),('A'),('B');
-- Add some Series (note that SeriesLeagueId is null when inserting)
INSERT INTO Series (Seriesname) VALUES('Test1'),('Test2'),('Test3');

UPDATE Series 
    SET SeriesLeagueID = (
        SELECT LeagueId 
        FROM League 
        WHERE Leaguename = 'Premier'
    ) 
    WHERE SeriesName = 'Test2';
```

The result being :-

[image]

Comment: I understand the concept of your explanation above.  It's pretty straight forward.  How would I go about getting the leagueID when I am starting a new series. At this point I haven't given the series a name yet like in you example above.

Comment: The LeagueID would be determined either by it's name or id (typically a spinner/dropdown is used for such a purpose) (id is actually the better as it unqiuely identifies a row (if defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)). How you actually do this is is dependant upon your code and requirements, so it's basically impossible to be specific.

Comment: @RobertVogl if this answers your question then please tick this as the answer.

Comment: While I understand your concept of having the Leagues pre populated, this is not feasable.  The user is creating the leagues and the long id needs to be passed on to the next activity to be written in the bowler table in  COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID.  I have been attempting to pass the League Primary Key to the next activity but it is not displaying it.

Comment: I have attached snippets of my code above.  Not sure if I am making this more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: @RobertVogl, this should be a new question.